# how to get only one node name from kubectl get nodes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is there any way that `kubectl get nodes` would output for example only one node name without any other info just the name? for example node ending with 1.

so instead of something like this:

```
NAME                                STATUS   ROLES   AGE   VERSION
aks-nodepool1-00000000-vmss000000   Ready    agent   1m   v1.23.12
aks-nodepool1-00000000-vmss000001   Ready    agent   1m   v1.23.12
```

just this
`aks-nodepool1-00000000-vmss000001`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the output option:

```
 -o, --output='':
        Output format. One of: (json, yaml, name, go-template, go-template-file, template, templatefile, jsonpath,
        jsonpath-as-json, jsonpath-file, custom-columns, custom-columns-file, wide). See custom columns
        [https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/#custom-columns], golang template
        [http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#pkg-overview] and jsonpath template
        [https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/].
```

So you can do

```bash
kubectl get nodes --output name
```

Comment: IIRC, doesn't `--output name` output the resource type too -- e.g. in this case, it would output `node/{name of node}`

Comment: @BlenderFox, yes thats right. I also thought about that yesterday, after posting. But i figured if OP accepted it, he is fine with that. You can use another output option such as custom-column to get only the name, or having the full identifier is good enough for you. In many cases the full identifier is more useful when wanting to use that thing in kubernetes again.

Comment: Yeah, he can either `cut` the output from that or `grep`|`awk` the main listing so nonetheless, good answer :)

Comment: yeah, I just did `kubectl get nodes --output name | sed '1d' | cut -c 6`, and works for me